# Gwt, the Dilemma of TabPanel, TabLayoutPanel & Custom Tab using TabBar +DeckLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, tabpanel

My app has a need to store many Panel dynamically. So TabPanel is the suitable choice. However, TabPanel only works in Quirks Mode, it can also work in Standards Mode but with some Quirks, ex, when u click a link put inside a TabPanel then there is a small shaking appeared. But TabPanel is pretty simple, not heavy & easy to code.

I am not sure if i put link into a HTMLpanel & then put that HTMLPanel into that TabPanel then the shaking problem will be solved or not?

Some others say do not use TabPanel cos its behavor is unpredictable in many different webbrowsers since it support only Quirks Mode. They prefers to use TabLayoutPanel. Ok, TabLayoutPanel is very stable solid, but it is quite complicated, it must be put into the RootLayoutPanel. If I don't put it into RootLayoutPanel, then i have to set its fixed width & height (ex: 600px 300px) to be able to see it in Non-root presenters. But I want its height + width to stretch out to 100%. Some peopl have problems with TabLayoutPanel so they have to switch to TabPanel but TabPanel may be deprecated in the future.

So, some suggest me to use custom TabPanel using TabBar + DeckLayoutPanel, but i couldn't find any UiBinder guide for how to use TabBar + DeckLayoutPanel to make custom TabPanel.

If u have to use Tab in ur app (in respect to the above constraints, ie run smoothly in standards mode & not put into RootPanel) then which solution will u choose?

What approach is the best?

Answer (score 0):

I use the TabLayoutPanel where possible.

When I need a tab panel that does not use the entire window or I want the tab contents to take just the side needed for the selected tab then I use a custom made TabPanel. That one is using the TabLayoutPanel for showing the tabs but the contents are put outside in a FlowPanel.